# Vertically align a child div element with parent div having dynamic height

Tags: css

How do I vertically align a child element with the parent having a dynamic height.

CSS code:

```
parent{
    height: 400px;
}
.child{
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%;);
}
```

This sets the child once, then doesn't change.  How do I change it so that it changes with the dynamic height of the parent?

Comment: these may helps you - https://jsfiddle.net/oe5g1sxc/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `display: flex`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.child {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

You can use `displa: flex`.

The following doesn't rely on parent's height.
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't use flex . flex have various issues in browsers use these- https://jsfiddle.net/c1rk2q37/

Comment: That solution is super hackish. What is the problem with flex-box? It's supported [pretty well](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and works in this simple case in all major browsers.

Comment: @Lazar...super cool link..

Comment: I think you should read the question first properly, It clearly mentions that the height and width comes dynamically not 100px . Its very easy to set in vertical while you know the width and height..

Comment: @moiduldargahi I specified the height and width because I have to specify _something_. If you change the height and width, it still works. You should test the solution properly.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović oh really :P then make the parent div height and width 100% you will get the result

Comment: @lazar..thanks...display:flex with some changes worked for me...

Comment: @moiduldargahi You cannot set it to a `100%` in the code snippet here because `100%` means `100%` of **its parent**, and the parent of `.parent` has no specified size. You can fiddle with the width and height and see that, no matter what you change it to, it will remain in the perfect center. The code doesn't reply on `width` and `height` properties of `parent`.